# NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 91: Controller method not found

Tags: laravel

Here is my controller..

```
public function postUpload() {
        if (Input::hasFile('file')) {

            $files = Input::file('file');
            $file = fopen($files, "r");
            while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $insert = ImportModel::create(array('company_name' => $emapData[0],
                            'contact_person' => $emapData[1],
                            'state' => $emapData[2],
                            'city' => $emapData[3],
                            'country' => $emapData[4],
                            'email_address' => $emapData[5],
                            'category' => $emapData[6]
                ));
            }//WHILE BODY
            //foreach($insert as $emapData => $values){
            //  echo $emapData.'<br>';
            //}
            if ($insert) {

                echo "done";
            }//INNER IF BODY
        }//IF BODY   
    }//POST UPLOAD FUNCTION
```

Here is my Route.php

```
Route::get('/file', array('as' => 'getfile','uses' => 'AdminController@getFile'));

Route::post('/file', array('as' => 'postUpload','uses'=>'AdminController@postUpload'));
```

I'm trying to import Excel CSV file into database, but when i hit import button it says controller method not found, Please help me..
thanks in advance

Comment: this is my form action

Comment: <form action="{{URL::route('postUpload')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: If i remove method="post" so it will not show this error controller method not found, and if i change it to method="get" then same it will not show error, but not working

Comment: Have you tried to run command `composer dump-autoload`? if not then try it from terminal/cmd.

Comment: My above code is right ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5, try :

```
 <form action="{!!route('postUpload')!!}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: not working, tried.. @Digitlimit i test these code on another project i made fresh, and on that project same code is working.. But on other project i just embed these coding and not working.. i show you my full admincontroller

Comment: Do you have other routes listed? It could be clashing with another route

Comment: May I see your routes.php

Comment: Route::controller ('/','AdminController');

Comment: Route::get('compaign', 'AdminController@getBx');

Comment: Route::get('/test', array(

 'as' => 'getTest',
 'uses' => 'AdminController@getTest'));

Comment: Route::post('/test', array(
 
 'as' => 'postUpload',
 'uses' => 'AdminController@postUpload'));

Comment: Route::get('/send', array(
 
 'as' => 'getSend',
 'uses' => 'AdminController@getSend'
));

Comment: i have these routes, all i sent you in comment

Comment: add things to your original post, dont just make 20 comments